# Disabling echo service in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, echo

Please, explain me what is echo service in Linux and how can I disable it?

For example, now I can type "echo hello" and it will print in the terminal "hello".

Thanks.

Comment: `mv /bin/echo /bin/echo.bak` but everything will be destroyed...your call

Comment: @ГлебШ `echo` is a command (not a service) that prints things you tell it to print, and *a lot* of scripts etc. depend on it. What on earth makes you think you would ever want to disable it?!

Comment: What do you mean by echo "service"? Echo is a command you can call to write to `stdout` (usually meaning print to the terminal).

Answer (score 0):

`echo` is a terminal command that simply prints its arguments to the console, as you observe.

`man` is another command which gives instructions on usage of a command. It stands for 'manual'. Therefore, to learn more about the `echo` command, you can run `man echo`.

It is **not recommended** to remove the `echo` command from your system, since it is part of GNU Coreutils, which is an essential part of the system. If you remove it, there is a **high possiblity you may break your system**.

However, you may remove it with:

```
$ su
# rm /bin/echo
```

The `su` command will prompt for the administrator password, and if correctly given, will put you in root. This is required because 'normal' users do not usually have permission to remove essential system components.

You can exit root with the `exit` command.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` is a command used to print text to `stdout`. Normally this just means writing to your terminal as you mention:

```
$ echo 'Hello world'
Hello world
```

For more information on this command, you can read the manpage. Here is the output from my machine:

```
$ man echo
NAME
       echo - echo - display a line of text


echo - display a line of text
   Synopsis
       echo [STRING]

   Description
       echo displays a string of text.

       The following options are available:

       · -n, Do not output a newline

       · -s, Do not separate arguments with spaces

       · -E, Disable interpretation of backslash escapes (default)

       · -e, Enable interpretation of backslash escapes

       · -h, --help Display this help

   Escape Sequences
       If -e is used, the following sequences are recognized:

       · \\ backslash

       · \a alert (BEL)

       · \b backspace

       · \c produce no further output

       · \e escape

       · \f form feed

       · \n new line

       · \r carriage return

       · \t horizontal tab

       · \v vertical tab

       · \0NNN byte with octal value NNN (1 to 3 digits)

       · \xHH byte with hexadecimal value HH (1 to 2 digits)

   Example
       echo 'Hello World' Print hello world to stdout

       echo -e 'Top\nBottom' Print Top and Bottom on separate lines, using an escape sequence
```

As far as disabling it, I can't think of any good reason to do that. As was mentioned in the comments, you could delete or move the binary so that the command cannot be called, but that just seems to be a *bad* **bad** ***bad*** idea, so I won't even mention how to do that here.